# Set priority to events

Tags: qt, serial-port, priority-queue

I am making an application in QT. I use QExtSerialPort to receive data from the serial port of my comp (whenever the readyread() signal is emitted). I also have some timers running doing other stuff at certain intervals. Now I noticed that when the timers are turned on, not all the data of the readyread signal is emitted a lot less, then when the timers are not turned on. Is there a way in QT to make sure that all the data of the serial port is received? Maybe by setting a high priority to the readyread event or something like that?

Comment: what baud rate are you using?  you could slow it down.

Comment: at the moment 115200, its supposed to collect data at about 500hz

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is difference between signal-slot connections and event system. Signal emitting and slot triggering are not separate things — when signal is emitted, connected slots begin to work. So they (signals) can't be lost.

All events are sent through application, and also are received, but it can happen later. When control returns to the main event loop, all events that are stored in the queue, will be processed.

If you are posting events yourself, you can use
`static void QCoreApplication::postEvent ( QObject* receiver, QEvent* event, int priority );` method.
Events are sorted in descending priority order, i.e. events with a high priority are queued before events with a lower priority. The priority can be any integer value, i.e. between INT_MAX and INT_MIN, inclusive; see Qt::EventPriority for more details. Events with equal priority will be processed in the order posted.

Comment: Please consider that Qt framework converts signals into events. This means that even signals are stored into event queue and might executed with small delay.

Comment: Default if the signal is emitted from a different thread than the receiving object, the signal is queued, behaving as Qt::QueuedConnection and as an event. Otherwise, the slot is invoked directly, behaving as Qt::DirectConnection. Only connection can be queued, not signal emitation. So you are little wrong here